# readonly property setter

Tags: c#, properties

After a extensive debugging session I found that the problem was that I called the setter of a readonly property. Is there a trick to provoke a compiler warning when this happens? Because marking the setter private does not work.

Cheers,

CA

---

To make clear what I mean:

```
    private readonly List<SomeObject> _budget;
    public IEnumerable<SomeObject> Budget
    {
        get
        {
            return _budget;
        }
    }
```

Can be accessed with

```
A.Budget=new SomeObject();
```

without compiler {error,warning,message}

Comment: In what scenario? 100% sure that if you call a private setter from code outside of the class, that won't ever compile.
Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't see how this could work without an error.  It looks like you want `A.Budget=new List<SomeObject>();` but even then it should still give an error saying "Property or indexer 'Budget' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"

Comment: @drs9222: Agreed; `A.Budget` is not assignable in the code that's listed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You mixed something up here. In your example the compiler will yield an error if you try to do `A.Budget=new SomeObject();` if the property `Budget` in class `A` does not have a setter.
From here on I can only **assume** what your problem is.

My guess is that you would like the collection wrapped in the `Budget` property to be readonly. That's probably why you made it `IEnumerable<SomeObject>` whereas the private member is a `List<SomeObject>`. So even if you do do not have a setter you can still do `(A.Budget as List<SomeObject>).Add(bla)`. To prohibit this you can use [List.AsReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx) like this:

```
private readonly List<SomeObject> _budget;
public ReadOnlyCollection<SomeObject> Budget
{
    get
    {
        return _budget.AsReadOnly();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops, you're right. Should have checked a third time before posting

Comment: @AnonymousCoward does this mean you do get an error?  I know you've got your answer but I'm curious about what actually happened.

Answer (score 8):

If your property has a setter, it isn't read-only. Remove the setter to make it read-only.

```
public string MyProperty // not read-only
{
    get { return myPropertyBacking; }
    set { myPropertyBacking = value; }
}

public string MyProperty // read-only
{
    get { return myPropertyBacking; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the setter.

Answer (score 0):

As it is it doesn't make sense but if you meant something like this for your example...

```
private readonly List<SomeObject> _budget;
public List<SomeObject> Budget
{
    get
    {
        return _budget;
    }
}
```

Can be accessed with

```
A.Budget.Add(new SomeObject());
```

That would work without error.

### EDIT

bitbonk's latest edit is exactly where I was going with this! I was just waiting for confirmation of the problem.